# Docker Compose file access issue when building

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I recently had a new developer join my team, and when she tries to build a local dev env via the docker-compose command she's getting a file access problem "Can't add file [x] to tar: io: read/write on closed pipe" - [x] is a variety of different files, most commonly kinesis-mock.jar from Localstack.

I couldn't replicate this problem until I reinstalled Docker Desktop (v4.27.1 for a Mac M1). I've tried a variety of versions of Localstack: we were on 1.2.0, I've gone through 1.3.0, 1.3.1 and 1.4.0 before trying 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, all with similar results, the only thing that varies is the file mentioned in the error. Usually it's a jar from Localstack, once it's been a ttf font file that was nothing to do with Localstack.

The code we're using is open source - repo is at https://github.com/DEFRA/rod-licensing, Dockerfile is here: https://github.com/DEFRA/rod-licensing/blob/develop/Dockerfile.base and yaml is here: https://github.com/DEFRA/rod-licensing/blob/develop/docker/services.build.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like something has changed in Docker since the services.build.yml was created, as the docker file ref in settings.build.xml isn't being honoured so rod_licensing_base and rod_licensing_builder weren't being created.
Directly building the two images by doing `docker build -t rod_licensing/builder - < Dockerfile.build` and `docker build -t rod_licensing/base - < Dockerfile.base` resolved the problem.